# Do PBKDF2 keys generated at a lower iteration count leak information?

Tags: key-derivation, pbkdf-2

Assume the threat model here is that the server is not to be trusted and the client is trusted. A user registers for an account and the client chooses an iteration count of 50,000 to generate a 512 bit key for the user.

The key is then split in half: the first half is kept locally as the encryption key, and the second half is sent to the server as the user's "password".

```
key = pbkdf2(password: inputted_password, salt: some_salt, cost: 50000, size: 512)
encryption_key = key.first_half
server_password = key.second_half
```

`server_password` is sent to the server to authenticate.

Assume now that on some subsequent login session, the client is tricked by some irrelevant means into computing `server_password` using a lower iteration count of 3,000 instead of the real value of 50,000.

So the client is tricked into using a lower cost:

```
key = pbkdf2(password: inputted_password, salt: some_salt, cost: 3000, size: 512)
server_password = key.second_half
```

and this `server_password` is sent to the server.

My question is, does this "weaker" derived password leak any information to the server on what the nature of the user's original inputted password is?

Answer (score 4):

Knowledge of `server_password` computed with 3,000 iterations instead of 50,000 makes it over 16 times faster to brute-force `inputted_password` and find `encryption_key` than was otherwise possible.

`server_password` can take much more values ($2^{256}$) than `inputted_password` can be tested, and PBKDF2 behaves like a random function, thus the first `inputted_password` found matching (if any) is the true one with overwhelming certainty.

Having found `inputted_password`, the adversary computes `encryption_key` by applying the same relatively low cost technique that generated it in the first place. That also allows to check that `inputted_password` is right (that is, the user did not misskey while s/he was tricked to use a lower iteration count; but even if that was, that could be worked around by trying small variations).

Comment: Is there no advantage gained here by the fact that the server is only receiving the second half of the key? So in order to brute-force the password, they would have to arrive at a string whose second half is the given string. I can see that if it was the first half the server was provided with, this would be a considerable advantage to the server. But what about with only the second half?

Comment: @Snwoman: Yes, there is advantage gained by the fact that the server only received the second half of the key: it does not know the other half, and brute-forcing the password is about the best attacks to find that other half, that is the encryption key. An attack lowering the iteration count makes brute-forcing both the password and the encryption key easier, by a factor of about 16.